# Python code that needs some overview

Tags: python

im currently learning python (in the very begining), so I still have some doubts about good code manners and how should I proceed with it.

Today I created this code that should random trought 01 to 60 (but is running from 01 to 69)

```
import random

dez = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
uni = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
sort = []

while len(sort) <= 5:
    random.shuffle(dez)
    random.shuffle(uni)
    w = random.choice(dez)
    z = random.choice(uni)
    chosen = str(w) + str(z)
    if chosen != "00" and chosen not in sort:
        sort.append(chosen)
    print chosen
```

I'm also in doubt how to make the code stop at "60".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do realize you can write the exact same code in 1 line, right? It is easy using [randint](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.randint):

```
>>> [random.randint(1,60) for _ in range(6)]
[22, 29, 48, 18, 20, 22]
```

This will give you a list of 6 random *integers* between 1 and 60. In your code you are creating *strings* that have these numbers. If you are deliberately creating them as strings, however, you then can do this:

```
>>> [str(random.randint(1,60)) for _ in range(6)]
['55', '54', '15', '46', '42', '37']
```

Comment: [str(random.randint(1,60)) for _ in range(6)] to be exact. :)

Comment: Ah, touche on the amount of random numbers. I really don't think he actually wants them as strings, though, that's just the approach he took.

Comment: Im feeling really dumb right now

The only part i didnt get is I tought the "for/in" interation were only for getting the list variables, didnt know it work as a counter  also

Comment: The reason for the strings is that I should output this as some text, but again now it dont look like I need it now

Answer (score 2):

You can just use

```
random.randrange(1,60)
```

Comment: What would be the difference beetween randrange and randint?

Comment: From Python 2.6 source: 
<code>def randint(self, a, b):
  return self.randrange(a, b+1)</code>

Answer (score 1):

To get 6 unique random integers in the range from 1 to 59:

```
sample = random.sample(xrange(1, 60), 6)
# -> [8, 34, 16, 28, 46, 39]
```

To get strings:

```
['%02d' % i for i in sample]
# -> ['08', '34', '16', '28', '46', '39']
```

Answer (score 0):

you will get no real benefit by shuffling on each loop. Do it once before the loop.

choosen isn't a word

Comment: True, also looks like shuffling on each iteration would be a huge loss of performance correct?

Comment: The random.choice actually obliterates the need for any random.shuffle.